# AutoMapperMappingException - Context: Trying to map String to String. error

Tags: automapper

I'm trying to map between two classes and am getting the following exception

```
3) Exception Information
********************************************* 
Exception Type: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException
Context: Trying to map String to String.

Mapping types:
String -> String
System.String -> System.String

Destination path:
ChildCareCasePaymentAdjRequestEntity.UserId.UserId
```

The source property in VB.Net

```
<DisplayName("User Id"), StringLength(6), Required()>
Public Property UserId As String
```

The destination property in c# is

```
[Required]
[StringLength(6)]
public string UserId
{
    get { return _userId; }
    set { _userId = value.ToUpper(); }
```

---

EDIT 
Automapper configuration in VB.Net is below.  I was trying to keep it very basic.

```
 Mapper.CreateMap(Of SourceModel, DestinationModel)()
```

Comment: Can you show your AutoMapper configuration?

Comment: I got the same error message when I performed some logic in the set method. A suggestion, for testing purposes, remove .ToUpper and the [StringLength(6)]